# Decoding floating point number in simple.json Java

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to read and parse a json file using simple.json in Java. However, on floating point numbers I get error. How should I parse floating point numbers?

The JSON File is like:

```
[
  {
    "region":"NF",
    "destination":"d1",
    "source":"s1",
    "time":2003,
    "value":0.1
  },
  {
    "region":"NF",
    "destination":"d2",
    "source":"s2",
    "time":2004,
    "value":0.002
  },
]
```

My code to parse it is:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)obj;
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    JSONObject jsonObject = iterator.next();
    String region = (String) jsonObject.get("region");
    String src = (String) jsonObject.get("source");
    String dst = (String) jsonObject.get("destination");
    long time = (long) jsonObject.get("time");
    long val = (long) jsonObject.get("value");
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? A sample JSON input, and code reading this input would help understand the problem better!

Comment: Can you show us something that would enable someone to answer this?  Like the JSON file that you're trying to parse?  Or the code that you're using?  Maybe even the error message?  Anything, so we can see what the problem is.  Thank you.

Comment: Don't know anything about "simple.json", but a floating-point number should generally come through from JSON as a subclass of Number.  You should be able to apply `doubleValue()` to it without having to determine the specific class returned.

Comment: I completed my question. Any ideas?

Comment: So your error is that `0.002` gets rounded down to `0` when you cast it to `long`, is that right?

Comment: No, it just produces error. java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: Even when I cast it to doube.

Comment: JSON-Lists mustn't contain any trailing commas. However some parsers are patient with this rule, don't know about simple.json's behaviour.

Comment: Can you link to the Java library (ideally the Javadocs) that you are using?

Comment: You're receiving a `Double`, not a `double`.  You must use one of the methods of `Number` to retrieve the value.

Comment: `Number number = (Number) jsonObject.get("value");  double val = number.doubleValue();`  (or `long val = number.longValue();`)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to store a floating point number, then you need a variable of that type, i.e., a double.

```
double val = ((Number)jsonObject.get("value")).doubleValue();
```

In this case, the `get()` method should return an instance of [java.lang.Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).  Then you can call the `doubleValue()` method to store the floating point value.

Comment: Note that OP is (presumably) asking about the [json-simple library](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), not the [JSON.org library](http://www.json.org/java/index.html).

Comment: @maerics Edited answer to fit the library requirement, thanks!

Comment: Does `get` return a `Number`?  If it returns `Object` then `doubleValue` will not apply.

Comment: In which case, this won't actually compile.

Comment: Thanks! Issue solved. In simple.json values are returned as Object. So a casting to Number is required. Number val = (Number)jsonObject.get("value");                    double value = val.doubleValue();

Comment: Actually, I am not sure what it returns. So I'll use a cast to Number in case.

Answer (score 1):

In Java EE 7, use `jsonObject.getJsonNumber("key").doubleValue()` to get the double value.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonNumber.html

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this library (I'm guessing it's [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) from your tag) returns numeric types as type `double`.

```java
Double value = (Double) jsonObject.get("value");
```

For example (tested and working with json-simple-1.1.1):

```java
String jsonString = "{\"foo\":1.23}";
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(jsonString);
Double d = (Double) obj.get("foo"); // => 1.23
```

Comment: I get this error when I do this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: @user1720860: note that both the type and the cast must be "Double".

Comment: The class used should be Number, which is "agnostic" and will cover either Double or Long.  Generally the parser will return integer values as Long and fractional values as Double.